# Scala : How to convert some to actual

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I am trying to get all attribute values of "Lr" type in a tab separated format. However, whenever I am executing "Echo" as below the program is returning :

```
Some(something1)    Some(something2)
```

Whereas, I am expecting :

```
something1  something2
```

Any clue on how to modify my code to get my expected format?

```
package com.......

case class Lr (
             some1_ID : Option[String],
             some2_ID : Option[String]
          )
{
   def getData(): String =
   {
      return productIterator.mkString("\t")
   }
}

object Echo {
   def main( args:Array[String] ):Unit =
   {
      val testLR = Lr(Option("something1"),Option("something2"))
      print(testLR.getData())
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you the owner of Lr case class? in that case, do you need to use Option[String]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what do you want to do in case some attribute is None.

If you want to discard None

```
case class Lr (some1_ID : Option[String], some2_ID : Option[String]) {
 def getData: String = {
   Seq(some1_ID, some2_ID).flatten.mkString("\t")       
 }
}
```

If you want to use an alternative value

```
case class Lr(some1_ID : Option[String], some2_ID : Option[String]) {
  def getData: String = {
    Seq(some1_ID, some2_ID).map(_.getOrElse("XXX")).mkString("\t")
  }
}
```

If you want to use productIterator, it is a Iterator[Any], so you need pattern matching in order to work with Options.

```
case class Lr(some1_ID : Option[String], some2_ID : Option[String]) {
  def getData: String = {
    productIterator.collect {
      case Some(value) => value
   // case None => "ALTERNATIVE VALUE"
   // case others => others   (non Option fields)
    }.mkString("\t") 
  }
}
```

Comment: what scala version are you using?

Comment: That is weird, Im testing it right now in the REPL with Scala 2.12.6. It's the same code?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to print for `None`? Decide that, then you can do something like

```
 def getData: String =
    Seq( 
      some1_ID.getOrElse("-"),
      some2_ID.getOrElse("-")
    ).mkString("\t")
```